# "Find Next" in the filename typeahead in the Project pane

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

In IntelliJ, when the Project pane (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>) is focused, you can start typing characters and it will try to find files whose names match the query.

If there are multiple files that match your string, is there any way to tell the Project pane to move to the next matching file?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself. Use the up and down arrow keys to jump between the alternatives.